# Calculating a Multivariable Limit

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to calculate a multivariable limit as follow:

$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{-ix^3y(x-iy)^2}{(x^6+y^2)(x^2+y^2)}$

Wolfram gives the answer as limit does not exist.

To show it, I am wanting to see if the limit does not agree once we take two directions in the complex plane.

Taking the direction $y=x$ we have:

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{-ix^4(x-ix)^2}{(x^6+x^2)(x^2+x^2)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{-ix^4x^2(1-i)^2}{(x^6+x^2)2x^2} =\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{-ix^4(1-i)^2}{2(x^6+x^2)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{-ix^4(1-i)^2}{2x^2(x^4+1)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{-ix^2(1-i)^2}{2(x^4+1)} =0$

I want to see what other possible direction I can use to get that the limit does not exist. I have tried $x=0,y=0,y=x^2$ but all give the same answer of $0$.

Any input on this would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: if $y=x^3$, then the limit for $x \to 0$ does not exist.

Comment: Thanks, so you get the limit does not exist as the limit taken with direction $y=x^3$ is $\frac{-i}{2}$ which is not equal to zero.

Comment: Sorry, I got a bit frustrated after taking multiple directions and getting zero... :P